# Using LIMIT to get AVG from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, limit

I currently have a query that gets every product_id FROM the receive_pallet TABLE. Along with every id it also gets the AVG of the date between when it is ordered/received (date_entered from the TABLE receive_pallet and date_ordered from the TABLE cs_po)

```
 SELECT a.product_id, avg(a.date) AS AVG
 FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF(date_entered,date_ordered) AS date,po_number_full, product_id
             FROM cs_po,receive_pallet
             WHERE cs_po.id = receive_pallet.po_number_full
             ORDER BY cs_po.id DESC )a 
 GROUP BY a.product_id;
```

The result would be something like:

```
 product_id     AVG
 00010005.01S   25.2500
 00010005.04D   19.0000
 00010010.01S   21.2680
 00010020.02S   15.1250
 00010040.04S   12.2400
 00010080.20S   16.6667
```

This query works, but i would like to LIMIT it to AVG the last 5 shipments, not all of them. This is the query i made to do so,

```
 SELECT a.product_id, avg(a.date) AS AVG
 FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF(date_entered,date_ordered) AS date,po_number_full, product_id
                                FROM cs_po,receive_pallet
                                WHERE cs_po.id = receive_pallet.po_number_full
                                AND product_id IN (SELECT product_id , date_entered,    date_ordered FROM receive_pallet LIMIT 0,5)
                                ORDER BY cs_po.id DESC
                                )a 
  GROUP BY a.product_id;
```

I get this error when i try to test it. [Err] 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME sub query'

I know i need to replace the IN() clause with an INNER JOIN as LIMIT simply isn't supported in an IN() sub query, But i don't know where to start if i have two sub queries/where to add the join. Thanks.

Comment: to which table does the fields `date_entered` and `date_ordered` belong?

Comment: Look at the comment above the first section of code.(date_entered from the TABLE receive_pallet and date_ordered from the TABLE cs_po)

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Working on it...

Answer (score 0):

Tale a look at this:

```
SELECT 
    a.product_id, 
    AVG(a.date) AS AVG
FROM (
        SELECT 
            DATEDIFF(date_entered, date_ordered) AS date,
            product_id
        FROM 
            cs_po c
                JOIN (
                    SELECT 
                        date_entered,
                        product_id,
                        po_number_full
                    FROM 
                        receive_pallet 
                    ORDER BY
                        date_entered DESC
                    LIMIT 5
                ) r ON c.id = r.po_number_full
        ORDER BY 
            c.id DESC
        ) a 
GROUP BY 
    a.product_id
;
```

I simplified it a bit, but I think it works the way you want.